# When clicking the button, if there is a Vbox with an ID, it calls an element controller method

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have the following code and I wanted to know if it is possible increment quantity of vbox node. This method below belongs to the Dashboard Controller class.

```
private void addProductToOrder(String id, String name, String price){
        for (Node node : order.getChildren()){
            if (Objects.equals(node.getId(), id)) {
                // call the addProduct() method of the Order Item Product class for the current node
                return;
            }
        }
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/luxrest/gui/components/orderItem.fxml"));
        try {
           VBox item = fxmlLoader.load();
           ((OrderItemController)fxmlLoader.getController()).setData(id, name, price);
           item.setId(id);
           order.getChildren().add(item);
        }catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In the OrderItemController class I have the following method:

```
public void addProduct(){
        quantityVal++;
        this.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantityVal));
    }
```

[Example UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hyui.png)

I want that when there is already an element on the screen not to add another vbox but to increase the quantity number.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. `Node` doesn't have a `getController()` method.  Can you create and post a [mre] so we can understand what the question is?

Comment: I tried to improve the question, I'm sorry but it's a bit complex to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addProductToOrder(String id, String name, String price){
    Node existingItem = order.lookup("#" + id);
    if (existingItem != null) {
        OrderItemController oic = (OrderItemController) existingItem.getUserData();
        oic.addProduct();
    }else{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/luxrest/gui/components/orderItem.fxml"));
        try {
            VBox item = fxmlLoader.load();
            OrderItemController oic = fxmlLoader.getController();
            oic.setData(id, name, price);
            item.setId(id);
            item.setUserData(oic);
            order.getChildren().add(item);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to get the expected result with the following code.